# Display please wait or a loader using javascript- REST API call

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I am writing a chrome extension to send data from the extension to an exposed REST Service. I am displaying a status message when i get a response from the API. I want to display a please wait or a loader while doing the API call essentially to tell the user that response has not yet been received from the server or when the server itself is down. Since its an asynchronous call I am not sure where to put the code to display the loader. Do I need to use a callback function? Here's my code-

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Send data to system Application</h2>

<form action="/action_page.php">
  <p>Please select:</p>
  <input type="radio" id="Credentials" name="CB" value="Credentials">
  <label for="Credentials">Credentials</label><br>
  <input type="radio" id="GeneralInformation" name="CB" value="GeneralInformation">
  <label for="GeneralInformation">General Information</label><br>
  <br>  
  
   <div id="ifCredentials" style="display:none">
        <form>
            Username <input type="text" id="Username" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            Password <input type="text" id="Password" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            URL <input type="text" id="URL" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            Environment <input type="text" id="Environment" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            Labels <input type="text" id="SVLabel" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
    
     <div id="ifGeneralInformation" style="display:none">
        <form>
            Description <input type="text" id="Description" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            URL <input type="text" id="GIURL" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
            Labels <input type="text" id="GILabel" style="line-height:3em"> <br><br>
        </form>
    </div>
        
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="submitButton" value="Submit">
  <div id="loader" style="display:none">Please wait...   </div>
  <div id="RESTStatus" style="display:none">
    <br> Status: <label id="RESTINFO">f</label>
  </div>
</form>


<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
    document.getElementById("Credentials").addEventListener("click", showRightData);

    document.getElementById("GeneralInformation").addEventListener("click", showRightData);

    document.getElementById("submitButton").addEventListener("click", callAPI);


function showRightData() {
     console.log("hel");
  if (document.getElementById('Credentials').checked) {
        document.getElementById('ifCredentials').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifGeneralInformation').style.display = 'none';
    }
    else if (document.getElementById('GeneralInformation').checked)
    {
        document.getElementById('ifGeneralInformation').style.display = 'block';
         document.getElementById('ifCredentials').style.display = 'none';
         chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, tabs => {
            let url = tabs[0].url;
                // use `url` here inside the callback because it's asynchronous!
                document.getElementById('GIURL').value=url;
            });
                
        
    }
        else
            {
            document.getElementById('ifGeneralInformation').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('ifCredentials').style.display = 'none';
            }
}

/*window.onload = function()
{
    
    document.getElementById('GIURL').value=window.location.toString();
}*/

function callAPI() {
    
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/cases";

    req.open("POST", baseUrl, true);
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");



    if (document.getElementById('Credentials').checked) {
        
        req.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
              "caseTypeID": "CB-systems-Work-Artifact",
              "processID": "pyStartCase",
              "parentCaseID": "",
              "content": {
              "ArtifactData": {
                       "ArtifactType":"Password",
                       "ArtifactUsername":document.getElementById('Username').value,
                       "ArtifactPassword":document.getElementById('Password').value,
                       "ArtifactURL":document.getElementById('URL').value,
                       "ArtifactEnvironment":document.getElementById('Environment').value,
                       "ArtifactLabels":document.getElementById('SVLabel').value
            }

        }
        }

            ));
    }
    
    else if (document.getElementById('GeneralInformation').checked)
    {
        
        req.send(JSON.stringify(
            {
              "caseTypeID": "CB-systems-Work-Artifact",
              "processID": "pyStartCase",
              "parentCaseID": "",
              "content": {
              "ArtifactData": {
                       "ArtifactType":"General",
                       "Description":document.getElementById('Description').value,
                       "ArtifactURL":document.getElementById('GIURL').value,
                       "ArtifactLabels":document.getElementById('GILabel').value
            }

        }
        }

            ));
        
        
        
    }
        
    
    
    req.onreadystatechange = function() { // Call a function when the state changes.
        if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && this.status == 201) {
                      document.getElementById('RESTINFO').innerHTML = "Successfully sent data to the system! API status: "+this.status;
            document.getElementById('RESTStatus').style.display = 'block';
           
        }
        
        else
            {
            document.getElementById('RESTINFO').innerHTML = "Failed to update the system! API Status: "+this.status;
            document.getElementById('RESTStatus').style.display = 'block';
          }
        
        
    }
    
    req.onerror = function() {
        document.getElementById('RESTINFO').innerHTML = "There has been an error. The status code is "+req.status;
            document.getElementById('RESTStatus').style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

Comment: Since asynchronous, i think you need to do a callback function to capture the waiting time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you already have most of the necessary code set up. All you need to do is add lines to show/hide the loader in the appropriate places.

To first show it, add this:

```
document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'block';
```

just before each of your two `req.send` calls. (You could add it just once at the start of the function, but it seems that you only send a request in one of two cases, so this has to be inside the `if` statements - you might want to show some message to the user if both of these fail to explain to them what is wrong and how to actually make the request.)

Then hide it with this:

```
document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
```

when the response is received. And in this case I think your code is incorrect, because you assume that an `readystatechange` event necessarily means that the request is finished (successfully or not), when in fact it happens at various stages on the way to that final state - see docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState).

What you should do, in the `onreadystatechange` callback function, is something like this:

```
req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // request is finished, so hide loader:
        document.getElementById('loader').style.display = 'none';
        if (req.status === 201) {
            // code for successful response
        }
        else {
            // code to handle unsuccessful response
        }
    }
}
```

Note that I'm using `req.status` instead of `this.status`, to avoid well-known problems with `this` inside callbacks.

The above rough outline should do as you want - but much of your code can be simplified and improved. And I would strongly suggest using the modern and widely-supported, Promise-based [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API rather than the rather old-fashioned `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: I think I needed a break on this one! :) Was pretty small. Thanks for the fetch API stuff. I am just learning java script :)